# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP HTTPS "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally "

Tags: vba, serverxmlhttp, msxml2

I have the following test  code in VBA in an EXCEL spreadsheet.
I am attempting to use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to retrieve JSON from a remote service (the final might require storing and sending cookies to create a session to get the date  so I am looking for the most flexible option which seems to be ServerXMLHTTP, I may be wrong here of course)

I was getting the run-time error -2147012866 80072efe "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally " when accessing a site with https

Looking at some [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611724/the-connection-with-the-server-was-terminated-abnormally-xmlhttp) suggested that this might be a firewall issue...
I turned off the windows firewall to test this and the results were the same.

After some experimentation MSXML2.XMLHTTP worked fine. 
Also if I access the same site using http I am not getting any errors. 
In this test code below I am getting the same error for both MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP and WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

```
 Sub TestRequest()
 Dim objHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
 Dim objServHttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
 Dim objWinHttp As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
 Dim URL As String
    'URL = "http://api.fixer.io/2017-10-10?base=gbp"
    URL = "https://api.fixer.io/2017-10-10?base=gbp"
   objHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
   On Error GoTo Error_request_1
   objHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objHttp.send ("")

Error_request_1:


   'objServHttp.setOption 2, objServHttp.GetOption(2) - SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS 'Ignore Possible certificate errors
   'objServHttp.setOption 2, 13056 'Ignore possible certificate errors
   objServHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
   On Error GoTo Error_request_2
   objServHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objServHttp.send ("")

Error_request_2:
    Stop

   objWinHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
   On Error GoTo Error_request_3
   objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objWinHttp.send ("")


Error_request_3:
    Stop

End Sub
```

I'm assuing I'm setting the wrong options, but I'm finding the documentation difficult to source for these...

Greatly appreciate any help trying to get these working for https.